# How to implement header bar on mobile views

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am building a Hybrid Mobile app with Angular 1.4x, Angular Material, UI-Router and Cordova. I am using UI-Router nested views to implement a global sidebar navigation view, but I have been adding the header bar markup to each content view since the title and some of the header action buttons are specific to the content view. This is causing a few problems:

- The header bar flickers during navigation since it is being removed and re-rendered with each transition
- I am duplicating quite a bit of markup for the header bar over and over including duplication of common buttons shared across all views (like hamburger button, etc).

It is convenient to be able to respond directly to header bar button clicks in the content view controller, but it feels lazy and violates DRY. It seems like the header bar should be a global UI element that provides an interface for content views to customize action buttons. I can't find any good blogs or examples on this.

Wondering how other developers handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a NavBar at the index.html, above the ui-view tag, when you change the view, you'll only change de ui-view tag or you can create a NavBar for each view, in any case, use ng-cloack to prevent this kind of issue.